# How Can I Add a Print Function To s Section Of this Algorithm To Print Out All Iterations That Has Been Made?

Tags: python, python-3.x, printf, brute-force

I'm working on a section in the Meet In The Middle Algorithm; also known as the "Collision Algorithm". Here's the code

```
Python 3 Program To Calculate The Discrete Logarithm Problem Using The Collision Algorithm

import math; 
  
def discreteLogarithm(a, b, m):  
  
    n = int(math.sqrt (m) + 1); 
  
    # Calculate a ^ n  
    an = 1; 
    for i in range(n): 
        an = (an * a) % m; 
  
    value = [0] * m; 
  
    # Store all values of a^(n*i) of LHS 
    cur = an; 
    for i in range(1, n + 1): 
        if (value[ cur ] == 0): 
            value[ cur ] = i; 
        cur = (cur * an) % m; 
      
    cur = b; 
    for i in range(n + 1): 
          
        # Calculate (a ^ j) * b and check 
        # for collision 
        if (value[cur] > 0): 
            ans = value[cur] * n - i; 
            if (ans < m): 
                return ans; 
        cur = (cur * a) % m; 
  
    return -1; 
  
# Driver code 
a = 2;
 
b = 3;
 
m = 5; 

print(discreteLogarithm(a, b, m)); 
  
# This code is contributed by mits.
```

I actually have a problem considering this section of the code...

My intention is to split this code into parts to apply them individually. In this section of this code below, i'm trying to apply a PRINT FUNCTION of some sort to print all iterations that has been stored but I'm not just getting it right.

```
# Store all values of a^(n*i) of LHS 
    cur = an; 
    for i in range(1, n + 1): 
        if (value[ cur ] == 0): 
            value[ cur ] = i; 
        cur = (cur * an) % m;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for the `print()` function? Here is an example of your code with some printouts. Note that there are unnecessary semicolons at the end of some lines of your code. I removed them.

```py
import math


def discreteLogarithm(a, b, m):

    _n = int(math.sqrt(m) + 1)
    print(f"_n = {_n}")

    # Calculate a ^ n
    print("### Calculate a ^ n")
    an = 1
    for i in range(_n):
        an = (an * a) % m
        print(f"an = {an}")

    value = [0] * m

    # Store all values of a^(n*i) of LHS
    print("### Store all values of a^(n*i) of LHS")
    cur = an
    for i in range(1, _n + 1):
        if (value[cur] == 0):
            value[cur] = i
        cur = (cur * an) % m
        print(f"cur1 = {cur}")

    cur = b

    # Calculate (a ^ j) * b and check for collision
    print("### Calculate (a ^ j) * b and check for collision")
    for i in range(_n + 1):
        if (value[cur] > 0):
            ans = value[cur] * _n - i
            print(f"ans = {ans}")
            if (ans < m):
                return ans
        cur = (cur * a) % m
        print(f"cur = {cur}")

    return -1


if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Driver code
    a = 2
    b = 3
    m = 5
    ans = discreteLogarithm(a, b, m)
    print(f"### discreteLogarithm({a}, {b}, {m})")
    print(f"ans = {ans}")

    # This code is contributed by mits.
```

Comment: Did you run the code to confirm some things..... I'm actually getting an "Indentation error"

Comment: Yes, this code works perfectly under Python 3. I tested it before posting it and I even tried a copy and paste from Stackoverflow and there is no problem. Just correct the line that has an indentation error and everything should be fine. I used 4 spaces for indentation. You have probably modified the code and your editor is configured to use tabs instead of spaces.